Compare $3^4 \times 6^5 \times 7^8 \bigcirc 4^3 \times 5^6 \times 8^7$
Compare
$$3^4 \times 6^5 \times 7^8 \bigcirc 4^3 \times 5^6 \times 8^7$$
Options:
$\text{(A)} > \space\space\space\space\space \text{(B)} <\space\space\space\space\space \text{(C)} =$

Notes:
$1.$ Calculators are prohibited.
$2.$ Students have no knowledge about logarithms, except a useful fact which is
$$\text{For }e<a<b, b^a<a^b, \text{where }e\approx 2.72$$
$3.$ Students should know rules of exponents, such as $a^m \times a^n = a^{m+n}, (a^m)^n=a^{mn}$, etc.
$4.$ It is not required to show the work. Therefore, any feasible approximation can be applied.
$5.$ The question should be answered in less than $2$ minutes.

This appeared in a national exam preparation book for my sister.
I claim that there is no typo. The reason for that is:
Previous question is:
Compare
$$3^4 \times 5^6 \times 7^8 \bigcirc 4^3 \times 6^5 \times 8^7$$
Which is marked as $\color{green}{\text{EASY}}$.
My solution to it is by using note $\text{#}2$ mentioned above. The answer is $\text{(A)} >$.
However, the current question is marked as $\color{red}{\text{HARD}}$

My attempt (did not give any conclusion):
Rearranging the numbers
$$\frac{3^4 \times 7^8}{4^3 \times 8^7} \bigcirc \frac{5^6}{6^5}$$
Then factor out one of the $5$'s
$$\frac{3^4 \times 7^8}{4^3 \times 8^7} \bigcirc \frac{5^5}{6^5}\cdot 5$$
Now using the rule which says $\frac{a^n}{b^n}=\big(\frac{a}{b}\big)^n$
$$\frac{3^4 \times 7^8}{4^3 \times 8^7} \bigcirc \bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^5 \cdot 5$$
Clearly, $\text{LHS}>1$ (using note $\text{#}2$ mentioned above).
Also $\big(\frac{5}{6}\big)<1 \implies \big(\frac{5}{6}\big)^5<1$
Now there are two possibilities:
I. If $\big(\frac{5}{6}\big)^5 \cdot 5<1$, then we can conclude that the correct option is $\text{(A)} >$
II. If $\big(\frac{5}{6}\big)^5 \cdot 5>1$, then we cannot conclude from this.
Then I realised that this approach is not feasible.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Option $(C)$ is wrong (which is not $\color{red}{\text{HARD}}$ to see). One side is divisible by $3$, the other not.

@DietrichBurde that is true, then A or B?

@CalvinLin Yes, using note $2$, we have $3^4>4^3$

@DietrichBurde We know that $5^6>6^5$ using note $2$. Then?

I had never seen this $\bigcirc$ notation. Where does it come from ?

@JeanMarie nothing but a space to fill, >, <.

Well if this is for your sister, then why doesn't your sister come on here and ask then?

@Mike she doesn't speak English. We are Arabs.

We can write the LHS as $2^53^97^8$ and the RHS as $2^{27}5^6$. Divide both sides by $2^5$ to get
$$
3^97^8 \bigcirc 2^{22}5^6
$$
From the LHS, we can get
\begin{align}
3^97^8 & = 3(21^8) \\
       & > 3(20^8) \\
       & = 3(2^810^8)
\end{align}
Conversely, from the RHS, we can get
\begin{align}
2^{22}5^6 & = 2^{16}10^6
\end{align}
We can then divide $2^810^6$ from both the LHS lower bound and the RHS to get
$$
300 > 256
$$

Edited to simplify the arithmetic.

To be honest, I knew which way to set the inequality because I know the logs of $2$ (and therefore $5$), $3$, and $7$ to five digits, although I only used three digits. Otherwise, it would have taken a bit more time.

One approach might be to show that $3^4 * 6^5 * 7^8 > 2^{41} > 4^3 * 5^6 * 8^7$. I'm having difficulty bounding the LHS easily, care to give it a try?

Wow! Prime factorisation. That is a nice approach. I know how to do Prime factorisation, but I did not understand the later calculations. I am trying now. Thanks for the answe (+1), and hope to do some edits so it can be simpler.

[This could reasonably be done in 2 minutes, esp if you started thinking about it in this way. It doesn't require guessing at what numerical inequalities to approximate by, nor doing tedious calculations.]
Let $ f(n) = \frac{ n^{n+1} } { (n+1)^n}$, which is the main object we want to study.
Lemma: $f(n) < f(n+1)$ for $ n \geq 0$.
Proof: $\frac{ n^{n+1} } { (n+1)^n} < \frac{ (n+1)^{n+2} } { (n+2)^{n+1}} \Leftrightarrow (n^2+2n)^{n+1} < (n+1)^{2n+2} = (n^2 + 2n + 1 ) ^ {n+1}$ .
Lemma: $f(3) > 1$
Proof: This is $3^4 = 81 > 64 = 4^3$, or OP's note 2.
Corollary: $f(7) \cdot f(3) > f(7) > f(6) >  f(5) $.
Hence $ 7^8 \times 6^5 \times 3^4 > 8^7 \times 5^6 \times 4^3$.
Notes

$f(n) \approx \frac{n}{e}$, hence the above lemmas.
It is true that $f(n)$ is increasing (EG via AM-GM or differentiation), though for our purposes it's sufficient to focus on the integer steps.
You can use this to construct similar looking inequalities.


$$3^4 \times 6^5 \times 7^8 \bigcirc 4^3 \times 5^6 \times 8^7$$
$$2^53^97^8\bigcirc 2^{27}5^6$$
$$3^97^8\bigcirc 2^{22}5^6$$
$$(\tfrac74)^2(\tfrac75)^6\bigcirc (\tfrac43)^9$$
$$(\tfrac74)^2(\tfrac75)^6\stackrel{?}{>} (\tfrac43)^3(\tfrac43)^6$$
$$(\tfrac74)^2\stackrel{?}{>} (\tfrac43)^3$$
$$\tfrac{49}{16}\stackrel{?}{>} \tfrac{64}{27}$$
Yes.

Prime factorization gives:
$$2^5 \times 3^9 \times 7^8 \bigcirc 2^{27} \times 5^6$$
Note that $3 \times 7 = 21 > 20 = 2^2 \times 5$.  Thus:
$$3^9 \times 7^8$$
$$= 3 \times 21^8$$
$$> 3 \times 20^8$$
$$= 3 \times (2^2 \times 5)^8$$
$$= 2^{16} \times 3 \times 5^8$$
Now we need to show that $2^{16} \times 3 \times 5^8 > 2^{22} \times 5^6$.  Or equivalently, $3 \times 5^2 > 2^{6}$.  This can easily be worked out by hand to get $75 > 64$, which is true.  By transitivity,
$$3^9 \times 7^8 > 2^{16} \times 3 \times 5^8 > 2^{22} \times 5^6$$
QED

Note $\text{#}2$?

@Hussain-Alqatari: I've removed all references to logarithms.

We can use that

$3^4=81>2\times 5 \times 8=80$
$6\times 7=42 >5 \times 8=40$
$ 7^2=49 >5 \times 8=40$

to obtain
$$3^4 \times 6^5 \times 7^8 \bigcirc 4^3 \times 5^6 \times 8^7$$
$$\left(\frac{3^4}{2\times 5 \times 8}\right)^2 \times 6 \times 7^8 \bigcirc 5^4 \times 8^5$$
$$\left(\frac{3^4}{2\times 5 \times 8}\right)^2 \times\left(\frac{6 \times 7}{5 \times 8}\right) \times 7^7 \bigcirc 5^3 \times 8^4$$
$$\overbrace{\left(\frac{3^4}{2\times 5 \times 8}\right)^2 \times \left(\frac{6 \times 7}{5 \times 8}\right) \times  \left(\frac{7^2}{5 \times 8}\right)^2}^{>1} \times 7^3 \bigcirc 5 \times 8^2$$
with $7^3=343 > 5 \times 8^2=320$, therefore $3^4 \times 6^5 \times 7^8 > 4^3 \times 5^6 \times 8^7$.

Given $e<a<b$ implies $b^a<a^b$, you get
\begin{align*}
7^8&>8^7\\
6^5&<5^6\\
3^4&>4^3
\end{align*}
So, this suggests that the LHS is likely bigger as two out of three times the bigger one is on the LHS, i.e. (A).
As $3^4>4^3$, it suffices to show that $6^5\times 7^8>5^6\times 8^7$, which can be demonstrated with the binomial theorem:
\begin{align*}
\require{cancel}
6^5\times 7^8&=6^5\times (8-1)^8\\
&>6^5\times \left(\cancel{8^8-\binom{8}{1}8^7}+\binom{8}{2}8^6-\binom{8}{3}8^5\right)\\
&=21\times 6^5\times 8^6\\
&=21\times (5+1)^5\times 8^6\\
&>21\times \left(5^5+\binom{5}{1}5^4\right)\times 8^6\\
&=2\times 21\times 5^5\times 8^6\\
&>5^6\times 8^7
\end{align*}
and the last line is because $2\times 21>5\times 8$. Now
\begin{align*}
6^5\times 7^8&>5^6\times 8^7\\
3^4&>4^3\\
\implies 3^4\times 6^5\times 7^8&>4^3\times 5^6\times 8^7
\end{align*}

A quick guess is that LHS > RHS. In fact, as long as $\dfrac{x^{x+1}}{(x+1)^x}$ is monotonic, then $LHS > RHS$
Consider $$f(x) =x\log(x+1) - (x+1)\log(x)$$
Then $e^{f(x)}=\dfrac{x^{x+1}}{(x+1)^x}$. Thus $\dfrac{x^{x+1}}{(x+1)^x}$ is monotonic over $f(x)$. We have:
$$f'(x) = \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) -\frac{2x+1}{x(x+1)}<\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2x+1}{x(x+1)} = \frac{-x}{1+x}$$
Clearly $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$, hence $f(x)$ decreases and
$$\frac{3^4}{4^3} > \frac{5^6}{6^5}>\frac{7^8}{8^7}>1$$
Therefore $$\dfrac{3^4\cdot 6^5 \cdot  7^8}{4^3\cdot 5^6 \cdot  8^7} > 1$$
